# error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'xxx'

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I'm getting a error when compiling 'error: expected nested-name-specifier before"

The code is

```
 using range = std::pair<float,float> ;
 range make_range( float a, float b ) { return { std::min(a,b), std::max(a,b) } ; }
 bool intersects( range a, range b )
 {
    if( a > b ) std::swap(a,b) ;
    return a.second >= b.first ;
 }
```

I'm using Ubuntun 12.04, GCC 4.6, and CodeBlocks 10.05

Comment: Make sure to include the required header files.

Comment: Before what, exactly?

Comment: See this [working example](http://ideone.com/QOnQhn).

Comment: C++11 type aliases are not properly supported in GCC 4.6. In GCC 4.8 it will work...

Answer (score 3):

I created this in a file:

```
 #include <utility>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iostream>

 using range = std::pair<float,float> ; 

 range make_range( float a, float b ) { return { std::min(a,b), std::max(a,b) } ; }

 bool intersects( range a, range b )
 {
    if( a > b ) std::swap(a,b) ;
    return a.second >= b.first ;
 }

 int main()
 {
   float x =1.0;
   float y =10.0;
   range pair_1 = make_range( x, y);
   range pair_2 = make_range(-2, 6);

   bool brs = intersects( pair_1, pair_2 );
   std::cout<<std::get<0>(pair_1)<<"  "<<std::get<1>(pair_1)<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<std::get<0>(pair_2)<<"  "<<std::get<1>(pair_2)<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<brs<<std::endl
   return 0;
 }
```

and using ***g++ -std=c++11 program_name.cc*** it compiled and ran without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant the following:

```
typedef std::pair<float,float> range;
```

Remember to use C++11 (or you will get the warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<algorithm>

using range = std::pair<float, float>;
range make_range(float a, float b) { return{ std::min(a, b), std::max(a, b) }; }
bool intersects(range a, range b)
{
    if (a > b) std::swap(a, b);
    return a.second >= b.first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not because of the header file, maybe because the c++ version is not c++11(try setting the compilation option to -std=c++11)

Comment: The same thing was already suggested by another answer